# Ember-Data cache for queries with params

Tags: caching, ember.js, ember-data

- Ember-Data caching in the > 1.13 world works fine as long as the find
  is fed with ids: /songs?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3 (Ember 1.13.11).
- In our use case the number of ids in case of one-to-many associations are high, typically more than 50.
- Because of the request length, Ember splits this in multiple requests to the
  backend. This increases load on the backend and delays the frontend, BUT the ember-data cache works fine.
- When I switch to /songs?playlist=1 which features a static parameter playlist, the backend response is all the same, BUT one request only, faster in total.
- But: Ember-data does not cache it (works as designed).

How can I use the second approach and get caching?

Thanks,
Manuel

Comment: when you say ember split you request into multiple requests do you mean 1 request per id ?

Comment: No, coalesceFindRequests is activated, so for one playlist with a many-to-many association to 84 songs, I see 2 requests, one with one part of the 84 song ids and a second one with the rest of the 84. I mean, with a switch to JSON API this will be just a link, but now our backend does not support it.